# Find duplicates based on a criteria and retain only record with latest timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where we have received many duplicate records. Ideally, order_nr should be unique for each record. But this is not the case for all the records but few.
We are still able to get matching records by comparing **serno1, serno2, model, branch,servicedate** fields.After finding all the duplicates by this way, we need to select only the records with latest timestamp on **imported** field.

DB: **SQL SERVER 2008**

**rawserviceaccum**
model, serno1,serno2,model,branch,servicedate,imported

Part 1 of finding the duplicates will be a self join. I am able to get all the duplicates into a tmp table. But between two records how can I retain only the records with maximum timestamp i.e,max(imported) from the list of records. I know that Aggregates and group by has to be used but I am not  able to successfully write any sql scripts for this.

If you do think there is any other way to approach this problem. Please do suggest.

Any help appreciated and much Thanks.

```
select * into #tmp from rawserviceaccum s
join(
select serno1 as serial1,serno2 as serial2,serviceDate as servicedate,
model as modelname ,branch as branchname,COUNT(*) as count 
from rawserviceaccum 
where company_code = 'abc' and period ='201401' 
group by serno1,serno2,serviceDate,model,branch
having COUNT(*) > 1) d
on s.serno1=d.serial1 and s.SERNO2 = d.serial2 and 
s.servicedate= d.servicedate and s.MODEL =d.modelname
and s.branch =d.branchname 
where s.COMPANY_CODE= 'abc' and s.period = '201401'                                             The table has around 20 more columns but I want to group by only the above mentioned columns to filter out any duplicates and delete records where imported date is not the latest. The table also has non duplicate records which should continue to exist.
```

I am so at my wits end with this problem. Help much needed. thanks.

Comment: What DBMS? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: I think, below query would give you result-> select serno1 as serial1,serno2 as serial2,serviceDate as servicedate,
model as modelname ,branch as branchname,COUNT(*) as count,max(imported) as latestImportedDate 
from rawserviceaccum 
where company_code = 'abc' and period ='201401' 
group by serno1,serno2,serviceDate,model,branch
having COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @simonatrcl sorry for not mentioning that it is sql server 2008.

Comment: @Gayathri, Yes, your query works perfect and gives only the records that have duplicates. What I didn't mention is the table also has other columns - around 20. But I would like to use group by with only the columns mentioned above(ser_no1,ser_no2,model,service_Date,branch).  I would like to delete the other duplicates retaining only the ones with latest import date. How to go about it? The table also has data which are not duplicates and which has to straight away be moved to the next table through another procedure. I am at my wits end with this problem. Very much need some help.

Comment: @SKa you can use Row_Number to avoid duplicate know

Comment: @Vigneshkumar Thank you for that. I think I have successfully designed a solution now. Learnt about Row_number as well today.